# pkg-config search path problems

Tags: debian, package-management

This shell session says it all for me:

```
root@debianvm:/home/matt# echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
/usr/lib/pkgconfig
root@debianvm:/home/matt# ls $PKG_CONFIG_PATH | grep libusb-1.0
libusb-1.0.pc
root@debianvm:/home/matt# pkg-config libusb-1.0 --cflags
Package libusb-1.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libusb-1.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libusb-1.0' found
```

Any ideas?  Looks to me like the `pkg-config` man page lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  This VM was configured to be a cross-build environment before I knew much, and I added the cross-build tools to the `PATH`.  The stripped-down ARM version of `pkg-config` works differently, I guess it has a different way of finding the `.pc` files.  Still working on that.  But my main problem was solved by removing the cross toolchain from the path, so the x86 `pkg-config` is being looked at.